# How to define and execute a function in python script?

Tags: python-3.7, blender

```
def calculation_of_salary(hours_worked,pay_per_hour):

salary = hours_worked*pay_per_hour
return salary

name = "kamil"

hw = 6

pph = 10

print("calculation_of_salary")
```

I know how to define but I don't know how to execute the function.
I'm fairly new to coding...
Looking for assistance

Thank you.

Comment: Why use the blender tag?

Comment: I've used the blender tag since I use scripting in blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this

```
def calculation_of_salary(hours_worked,pay_per_hour):
  salary = hours_worked*pay_per_hour
  return salary

name = "kamil"

hw = 6

pph = 10

print(calculation_of_salary(hw,pph))
```

live :
https://repl.it/@RKVKanyan/RoyalMediumorchidSale

Comment: you've been of great help, I'm fairly new to coding, this has helped me understand how linking works.